# Automapper map source to dest with custom object

Tags: c#, automapper

How I can map:

Object: (

```
   class CashCaseDTO { string CaseId {get;set;} double CaseTotalAmount {get;set; }
```

To:

```
public class CashCase
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

}

public class CashCaseDifference
{
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

I have problem with mapping `amount` to `Difference.Amount`.

What should I use? Custom Value resolver or converter?

Comment: Are you just trying to deserialize JSON to an object? If so, you could use Newtonsoft.Json. If not, what type is the source object?

Comment: Id and Amount shouldn't belong to the same class?

Comment: Look now at object

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45305965/automapper-custom-object

Answer (score 1):

This conversion is supported by default in the latest version.

Comment: No, it throws exception that child-type requires mapping

Comment: Yes, I'm just talking about string<->decimal.