# Automapper custom object

Tags: c#, automapper

How I have configure automapper to map this:

```
class Source { Guid Id; double Price; }
```

To this:

```
class Destination { Guid Id; DestinationDifference Difference; }


class DestinationDifference { decimal Amount; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: You should really read the FAQs on how to post a question and what information should be added. (No, I'm not the downvoter)

Here is an example how to get your mapping to work. Please note, that I've changed your classes a bit, because AutoMapper needs properties.

```
Source source = new Source();
source.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
source.Price = 10.0;

Mapper.Initialize(x => x.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .ForMember(a => a.Difference,
        b => b.MapFrom(s => new DestinationDifference() { Amount = (decimal)s.Price })));

Destination destination = Mapper.Map<Source, Destination>(source);
```

Classes:

```
class Source
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}

class Destination
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DestinationDifference Difference { get; set; }
}

class DestinationDifference
{
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: AM works by default with public fields and you can always configure what gets mapped. Of course mapping private fields is not a good idea :)